# Why facet showing wrong colors ..?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Obviously, it looks like a very simple issue. The following 2D facet [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1B4L.jpg) can be plotted without error. However, the facet plot mixes up colors and shapes. For instance, in this example the right hand column typically should only have blue marker, while the center column should show green ones.

```
 data1
 num     delay claim supply project
 1 -236.347551  3000    DIF   site1
 2   65.132011  5000    Hoc   site2
 3   61.401260  5000    Hoc   site2
 ..
 base04 <- ggplot(data1, aes(num, delay, size=claim, color=supply, shape=project))
 base04 + geom_point() + facet_grid( project ~ supply )
```

[facet plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1B4L.jpg)

Any ideas from your side ..

Comment: Edit your original question. Don't open a new post for the exact same question. See [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I attached the image now.

Comment: Attach it to your original post. And include sample data that recreates that plot. The data you provided does not.